# How to post json data using jquery

Tags: jquery, python, http-post, wsgi, bottle

I want to post JSON data to a url but below mentioned code is not posting data to server.

I am using the python bottle framework and a WSGI server.

It is not receiving the JSON data and the WSGI server is giving a 405 error.

**script**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#hi").click(function(){

var jsonObjects ='{"type":["FORGOT_PASSWORD"],"data":[{"hardwareID":"SAM1234567890123","emailID":"v@gmail.com"}]}';

jQuery.ajax({
      url: "http://192.168.0.135:8080/uid",
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json",
      data: JSON.stringify(jsonObjects),
      success: function(result) {
     //Write your code here
      }
});

});
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="submit" id="hi" />
<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data: JSON.stringify(jsonObjects),
```

since your json payload is already a string no need to stringify it, although i'm willing to bet if you stringify a string you get...

next thing is to ask what url you are posting from? only 192.168.0.135 will be allowed by your browser

lastly try adding some debug, console.log and console.dir are your friends :-)

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: "http://192.168.0.135:8080/uid",
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: jsonObjects,
  success: function(result) {
    console.log("success, check your server-side!");
    console.dir(result);
  },
  error: function(result) {
    console.log("error!");
    console.dir(result);
  }
});
```